# php scripts are running under apache uid

Tags: apache-2.2, php, suphp

I have a vps, running directadmin with apache 2 and php 5. It all worked fine, until today, since i discovered that PHP scripts are executed under apache:apache, and not under file's owner uid. This screwed up the entire system, but the main problem is that I can't figure out WHY would suphp stop working suddenly??

Some info:

```
root # php -v
PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2011 21:02:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

httpd.conf

```
User apache
Group apache
...
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
   <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_Engine On
        suPHP_UserGroup webapps webapps
    SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
   </IfModule>
</Directory>


<VirtualHost 192.168.56.55:80 >
        ...
    SuexecUserGroup robert robert
        ...
        <Directory /home/robert/domains/testing.com/public_html>
        Options +Includes -Indexes

        php_admin_flag engine ON
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

extra/httpd-php-handlers.conf

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc|php|php3|php4|php5|php6|phtml|phps)$">
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .inc .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</FilesMatch>
```

Whenever I run phpinfo() inside /var/www/html, or home/robert/domains/testing.com/public_html (with the file owner robert:robert), the result is the same: `User/Group  apache(48)/48`

How can i solve this?

- and suphp log is empty :(

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suPHP is likely not installed.

Since you are using conditional load statements, suPHP may have been removed on an Apache upgrade.

I don't work on DirectAdmin boxes any longer, but I know they used to be problematic with overwriting custom configurations.

1. Confirm that suPHP is indeed installed in Apache.  Use:

   httpd -l

to list built-in apache modules.  Or look for a Load statement in your configuration.  A quick ways to test is to comment the conditional load statements and then try to restart Apache.

2. Assure that suPHP is enabled on the domain and that the user/group specs are correct in the httpd configuration. (What you posted looks good.)
3. Once suPHP is enabled, you can likely just chown the directory to the correct user.

Comment: httpd -l shows mod_suexec.c. It was all working fine until yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, (from an admin's standpoint) suphp is a bad idea and dangerous.  Doubly so on a shared system.  That being said... are you sure suphp is being loaded?  You have a nicely formated  statement that would completely be ignored if the module failed to load or was missing.